# Is there a way to put multiple lines of code in a try except block and run then sequentially even if one throws an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, exception, try-catch

I'm doing some data analysis and creating new columns in a CSV file. Occasionally, as I'm iterating through lines in a pandas dataframe, I get a zero division error. When this happens, I pass to the next line.

Cleaner code:

```
try:
    self.sf1.loc[ind, 'quick'] = (row['assets'] - row['inventory']) / row['liabilities']  # Quick
    self.sf1.loc[ind, 'current'] = row['assets'] / row['liabilities']  # Current
    self.sf1.loc[ind, 'financial_lev'] = row['debt'] / row['equity']  # Financial Lev

except ZeroDivisionError:
    continue
```

The code above is much easier and cleaner than the other way that functionally works below. The only problem is, if any of the lines of code throw a `ZeroDivisionError` than none of the other lines of code are run.

Unclean solution:

```
try:
    self.sf1.loc[ind, 'quick'] = (row['assets'] - row['inventory']) / row['liabilities']  # Quick
except ZeroDivisionError:
    continue
try:
    self.sf1.loc[ind, 'current'] = row['assets'] / row['liabilities']  # Current
except ZeroDivisionError:
    continue
try:
    self.sf1.loc[ind, 'financial_lev'] = row['debt'] / row['equity']  # Financial Lev
except ZeroDivisionError:
    continue
```

Is there any way to do something more similar to the first code bubble while making sure that every line of code runs even if one above it throws an error? By the way, this try, except block is in a pandas `iterrows()` loop.

Comment: Write a function that does what you want, and call it on each line.

Comment: `continue` is wrong.  It's used in loops to skip the remainder of the loop and go on to the next iteration, so it would go back to the top of your `iterrows() loop` in this case and not work at all if not in the context of a loop.  Use `pass`, and you have to do the "unclean" method to skip a line that fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't: that's the semantic definition of the `try-except` scope.

I don't understand your complaint about using multiple PANDAS vectorizations, since both code examples use the same ones.  The only difference is the exception handling and continuation.

With your current code, note that if you hit a zero division on row 4, then rows 5-bottom will be untouched.
If you need line-oriented continuation control, then you'll have to perform all of the desired divisions explicitly, checking for the exception on every individual operation, rather than the entire vector as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping off @Barmar's comment, write a function like the following. Hard to say it's *better* than what you're doing, but it's closest thing to what you're asking. In general @Prune's answer is exactly right — the semantic definition of try-except requires this kind of verbosity.

```
def try_except_execution(ind, col1, numerator, denominator):
    try:
        self.sf1.loc[ind, col1] = numerator / denominator
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

Then just call it on each case:

```
try_except_execution(ind, 'quick', (row['assets'] - row['inventory']), row['liabilities'])

try_except_execution(ind, 'current', row['assets'], row['liabilities'])

try_except_execution(ind, 'financial_law', row['debt'] / row['equity'])
```